# BINLSVC warning in event log - netclass.inf parsing Manufacture

Tags: windows-event-log, windows-service, windows-server-2003-r2, wds, windows

So I am trying to get Remote Installation Service Running on a Windows Server 2003 R2 Standard Edition with Service Pack 2 installed. I am trying to integrate network drivers into the image and I keep getting this warning in the event log.

- Source: BINLSVC
- EventID: 1101
- Error Text:

> An error occurred during the parsing of an INF file netclass.inf in
>   the given section Manufacturer.

What's weird is that there is a KB article that talks about this [KB823658](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=823658). The problem is that the hotfix was rolled up into SP2 so it should already be applied.

Another weird thing is that the Boot Information Negotiation Layer Service (BINLSVC) is not displayed as a running service so I can't restart it when I make changes to the image. I do have the Windows Deployment Service (WDS) and I am hoping that it was rolled into that as well.

This is a system that has DHCP, DNS, and AD installed and I have run RISETUP.EXE . This all mostly done with the default values and this is in a test environment where there is very little else on the subnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service Pack 2 for Windows Server 2003 replaced RIS with WDS. You should only be using WDS at this point. This [Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/944350) (while the exact error may not apply) shows you how to manually uninstall RIS. Once that is complete, this TechNet article should help you: [Step-by-Step guide for Windows Deployment Services in Windows Server 2003](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766320(v=ws.10).aspx)

You might also want to look at current generation of deployment technologies with the [Microsoft Deployment Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=25175) which brings quite a bit of additional functionality to the deployment process. This includes managing device drivers, updates and even installing software during the deployment process. If it looks to be a fit for you, you could also MDT on a Windows Vista, 7, 8 or Sever 2008, 2008 R2, 2012 to connect to a deployment share on the server via network, or simply host the boot images in WDS on your existing server and the deployment share on the workstation. More information about MDT and WDS can be found on the Plan page and the Deliver page of the [Windows 8 Springboard Series on TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/hh771457.aspx).

Comment: Once I realized that BINLSVC is part of the WDS Service, it made a lot more sense. This error is driver specific and does not affect the deployment process. The problem I was having related to the intel driver not loading from the $oem$ location. I had to copy it into the i386 folder with everything else.

Comment: Also, after realizing that RIS doesn't like a lot of different software, I moved to a WDS method. It's more similar to the traditional "sysprep and duplicate" method of deploying windows.